# Why USB connected UPS device does not show up as /dev/ttyUSB0?

Tags: debian, usb-device, ttyusb

I'm connecting a Legrand Keor SP **UPS** device via USB to my Debian linux. The problem is that `/dev/ttyUSB0` is not created therefore I cannot communicate with the device.

After connecting I can see it added in `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 1cb0:0032                                  <<— THIS ONE
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0627:0001 Adomax Technology Co., Ltd
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

I can see the related `dmesg` messages:

```
[Jul19 12:03] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 5 using uhci_hcd
[  +0.201170] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1cb0, idProduct=0032, bcdDevice= 0.02
[  +0.000002] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=5
[  +0.000001] usb 3-1: Product: Legrand UPS
[  +0.000000] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Legrand
[  +0.183988] hid-generic 0003:1CB0:0032.0005: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Legrand   Legrand UPS  ] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input0
```

I can see the related `udev` messages:

```
UDEV  [1188.303843] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb3/3-1 (usb)
UDEV  [1188.304636] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [1188.305475] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/0003:1CB0:0032.0005 (hid)
UDEV  [1188.306728] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/0003:1CB0:0032.0005/hidraw/hidraw1 (hidraw)
UDEV  [1188.307283] add      /class/usbmisc (class)
UDEV  [1188.307957] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/0003:1CB0:0032.0005 (hid)
UDEV  [1188.308732] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/usbmisc/hiddev0 (usbmisc)
UDEV  [1188.309241] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [1188.310003] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb3/3-1 (usb)
UDEV  [1191.140181] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/usbmisc/hiddev0 (usbmisc)
UDEV  [1191.140554] remove   /usbmisc (class)
UDEV  [1191.141072] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/0003:1CB0:0032.0005/hidraw/hidraw1 (hidraw)
UDEV  [1191.141419] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/0003:1CB0:0032.0005 (hid)
UDEV  [1191.141618] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/0003:1CB0:0032.0005 (hid)
UDEV  [1191.142072] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0 (usb)
```

I also tried this trick to see whether the device is mapped to another `/dev` node but it isn't, nothing appears in /dev unfortunately: [How to allow software access to any USB devices?](https://askubuntu.com/a/632428/26246)

A small note although I don't think it's relevant is that my Debian is running inside of a Proxmox VE. The USB port is shared entirely with the Debian VM therefore I think it should be fine:

[image]

The device shows up exactly the same in `lsusb` of the Proxmox virtualization host:

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1058:25a2 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. Elements 25A2
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 1058:1140 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. My Book Essential (WDBACW)
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05c8:0815 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink)
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 1cb0:0032                                           <<— THIS ONE
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**UPDATE 2020-07-20:**

Updating `udevadm monitor -u` messages to eliminate confusion about device removal. The following gets printed every time I **plug in** the UPS into the USB port:

```
UDEV  [316.998469] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/0003:1CB0:0032.0002/hidraw/hidraw1 (hidraw)
UDEV  [316.998941] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/usbmisc/hiddev0 (usbmisc)
UDEV  [316.999325] remove   /usbmisc (class)
UDEV  [317.000298] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/0003:1CB0:0032.0002 (hid)
UDEV  [317.000534] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/0003:1CB0:0032.0002 (hid)
UDEV  [317.001022] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [317.001219] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [317.001737] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb3/3-1 (usb)
UDEV  [317.001902] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb3/3-1 (usb)
```

**UPDATE 2020-07-22:** New dump of `dmesg` when connecting the device to the host machine:

https://pastebin.com/raw/uFUUHGz6

**UPDATE 2020-07-30:** New dump of `lsusb -v` added:

https://paste.ee/p/56Lgl

Comment: One more note: the device shows up under `/dev/bus/usb/003/003` in the Debian VM, I am able to `cat /dev/bus/usb/003/003` but creating a symlink `ln -s /dev/bus/usb/003/003 /dev/ttyUSB0' does not help, the UPS is still not recognized by its software, therefore I think this is not the right way to go.

Comment: Update: it behaves exactly the same (i.e. doesn't work) when connected to a second Debian box directly (without virtualization) -> I think we can rule out Proxmox causing the problem.

Comment: The UPS might not use a serial protocol, in which case `/dev/ttyUSB0` wouldn’t be needed; the device identifies as a HID device, not a serial device. Have you tried [`nutdrv_qx`](https://networkupstools.org/docs/man/nutdrv_qx.html)?

Comment: @StephenKitt According to Legrand's manual it should be /dev/ttyUSBx or /dev/ttySx (https://ups.legrand.com/media/software/UpsComm_en.pdf). In Legrand's software you can only choose between those devices. I tried to install nut configure it with nutdrv_qx a moment ago but it says "No supported devices found. Please check your device availability with 'lsusb' …".

Comment: Udev rules show a HID device, that gets removed 3 seconds later. If you used `grep` on `dmesg`, please **read** the complete `dmesg` output and have a look if there are error messages in between adding and removing. If the reason for the removal is that you pulled it out again, then don't pull it out, and use `evtest` to look for then input device created on top of the HID device.

Comment: @dirkt Thanks amd sorry for the confusion. I edited my post and added a new udev output above. No grep had been used.

Comment: Now I am utterly confused. You plug in the device, and get `dmesg` entries saying a new device is found, but `udev` messages about removing it? Please do a fresh boot, wait until everything has settled, then plug in the device, and upload the complete `dmesg` (NOT udev) to a pastebin etc., and edit question with the link. Something is really really wrong here.

Comment: @dirkt Sure, I've added a pastebin dump after a fresh reboot (with USB disconnected) and then connecting the USB device to the host machine. Do you need anything similar from the guest VM?

Comment: And this one clearly says you got a HID device, and you should see hiddev0 and hidraw1 and probably input0 as well (your format is still different from what I normally see). No errors, no disconnects, so these devices should be there. Try with `evtest`, or try to dump from `hidraw1`, and see if you get anything.

Comment: @dirkt I ran the following `cd /dev; find -name "hiddev*"; find -name "hidraw*"; find -name "input*"` and I get `input` and `hidraw0` before plugging in the UPS and `hidraw1` and `usb/hiddev0` in addition to that when plugged in. `evtest` unfortunately does not show any additional devices. Nonetheless, I would say that the UPS should show up as a serial or USB device (ttyS0, ttyUSB0, …) therefore maybe the problem is that it registers as HID :(

Comment: So it could be that your UPS uses HID to communicate instead of serial, it could be that your UPS needs to be put into serial mode by issues some commands on HID, or it could be that your UPS has an alternate USB configuration that is serial (check with `lsusb -v`).  For the moment, you are not getting a serial, because that's what your UPS does, no matter what the documentation says.

Comment: @dirkt I contacted Legrand support but with no luck so far :( Legrand's Linux app needs to be configured by setting up the port which should be one of: /dev/ttyS0…5, /dev/ttyUSB0…5 or /dev/USB. That's why I assume that it should be a serial port by out of the box. I created a `lsusb -v` dump of the only device that appears after plugging in the UPS: https://paste.ee/p/56Lgl

Comment: There's only one configuration, which is HID. No serial configuration to be seen. You can have a look at the HID descriptor at `/sys/kernel/debug/hid/<dev>/rdesc` and use the `hidraw` device to send/receive data, in case support doesn't help. Do `mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug` first if necessary.

Comment: @adamsfamily I run into the same issue; eventually did you fix it? I am on a Fedora 35 machine, and wish to connect a Keor SP 800. I really appreciate any advise..

Comment: also, if anybody is looking at it, I think it is a issue of a missing drive.

Comment: @mario It is very sad but no one from Legrand was willing to help me :( I haven't been able to solve the particular issue with the driver but I did solve my core problem by buying a different UPS device and I'm very happy now. I went with a Cyberpower VP1600ELCD instead and it works like charm natively with 'nut' on Linux. No issues with the USB device whatsoever. This is the best advise I have, I'm sorry :(

Answer (score 2):

Legrand does not use `ttyUSB`, in `upssrv` settings select "USB".

I use UPS Communicator 1.32, but this has a bug for linux version and can't initialize connection to ups correctly.

Solution:

- Stop upssrv on Debian
- Start VM with Windows
- Forward USB port to VM
- Install UPS Communicator for Windows, run it and connect to ups

Now you can stop the VM and start `upssrv` on Debian - all will work fine until you unplug usb cabel or hard reset pc.

Comment: Wow, ths is almost embarassing from Legrand and genius from you! I can't verify this right now but I'll definitely try! Thanks!

Comment: "..embarassing from Legrand" - that is right. Few months ago I collected pcap from usb data transfer from Debian and Windows, sent it to Legrand it-support and still I dont get any answer. Last night I have tested latest version UPS Communicator from Legrand website (1.34) - the bug still stay.

Comment: Yes, I've contacted Legrand support in several countries months ago and still waiting for the answer. They really-really should open-source this tool, put it on GitHub and some of us would fix it.